# Uncaught ReferenceError: makeGrid is not defined?

Tags: javascript, conways-game-of-life, referenceerror

I am currently coding the 'Game of Life' simulation in JavaScript, but nothing is showing and it keeps saying that my variable makeGrid is not defined! even though I defnined a function makeGrid right beneath it! I don't understand what the issue is here.

```
 //object constructor
function cell(){
    this.alive = Math.random() >0.7;    
    this.neighbours = 0;  //number of live neighbours
}


function GoL(size){
    this.size = size;
    this.grid = makeGrid(size);

};      

GoL.prototype.makeGrid = function (size){
        var grid = [];
        for(var i=0; i<size; i++){
            var row=[];
            for(var j =0; j<size; j++){
                row.push(new cell());   
            }
            grid.push(row);
        }
            return grid;
    };  


GoL.prototype.drawGrid = function(){
        for(var i=0;i<this.size;i++){
            var row =this.grid[i];
            var rowString="";
            for(var j=0;j<this.size;j++){
                var cell = row[j];
                if(cell.alive){
                    rowString += "X|";
                }else{
                    rowString += " |";
                }               
            }
            console.log(rowString);
        }       
    };

var first = new GoL(20);
first.drawGrid();
```

Cheers.

Comment: You defined a *method*  `.makeGrid`. You'll need to invoke it as `this.makeGrid`

Comment: …or you need to actually declare it as a function (which is fine, given it's quite static): `function makeGrid(size) { … }`